# Java - How can I make this more space efficient?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, whitespace, performance

I've been asked to make this more space efficient, I'm assuming that I need to use loops but I'm not entirely sure how to, some help would be appreciated.

(For reference the aim of this piece of code is to display a graph into another program using data which has already been collected in the other program)

```
 public class StudentChart 
{
    public StudentChart(int[] moduleMarks)  //Constructor
    {
        Bar y = new Bar();
        y.makeVisible();
        y.changeSize(1, 100);
        y.moveVertical(100);
        y.moveHorizontal(-1);
        y.changeColour(Colour.BLACK);
        //y-axis is produced
        Bar x = new Bar();
        x.makeVisible();
        x.changeSize(200,1);
        x.moveVertical(200);
        x.changeColour(Colour.BLACK);
        //x-axis is produced
        draw(moduleMarks);
        printSummary(moduleMarks);
    }

    public static void draw(int[] moduleMarks)
    {

        int a = moduleMarks[0];
        int b = moduleMarks[1];
        int c = moduleMarks[2];
        int d = moduleMarks[3];
        int e = moduleMarks[4];
        int f = moduleMarks[5];
        //stores module marks from array as variables to be used later
        Bar mod1 = new Bar();
        Bar mod2 = new Bar();
        Bar mod3 = new Bar();
        Bar mod4 = new Bar();
        Bar mod5 = new Bar();
        Bar mod6 = new Bar();

        mod1.makeVisible();
        mod2.makeVisible();
        mod3.makeVisible();
        mod4.makeVisible();
        mod5.makeVisible();
        mod6.makeVisible();
        //Bars are initialised and made visible
        mod1.moveVertical(200-a);
        mod2.moveVertical(200-b);
        mod3.moveVertical(200-c);
        mod4.moveVertical(200-d);
        mod5.moveVertical(200-e);
        mod6.moveVertical(200-f);
        //Bars are moved based on their height so that they touch the x-axis
        mod1.changeSize(15, a);
        mod2.changeSize(15, b);
        mod3.changeSize(15, c);
        mod4.changeSize(15, d);
        mod5.changeSize(15, e);
        mod6.changeSize(15, f);
        //Bar height changes depending on the module marks
        mod1.moveHorizontal(0);
        mod2.moveHorizontal(35);
        mod3.moveHorizontal(70);
        mod4.moveHorizontal(105);
        mod5.moveHorizontal(140);
        mod6.moveHorizontal(175);
        //Bars are moved across so can be seen on chart
        if (a<35)
        {
            mod1.changeColour(Colour.RED);
        }
        if (a>= 35 && a<40)
        {
            mod1.changeColour(Colour.YELLOW);
        }   
        if (a>= 40 && a<70)
        {
            mod1.changeColour(Colour.GREEN);
        }
        if (a>= 70)
        {
            mod1.changeColour(Colour.MAGENTA);
        }

        if (b<35)
        {
            mod2.changeColour(Colour.RED);
        }
        if (b>= 35 && a<40)
        {
            mod2.changeColour(Colour.YELLOW);
        }   
        if (b>= 40 && a<70)
        {
            mod2.changeColour(Colour.GREEN);
        }
        if (b>= 70)
        {
            mod2.changeColour(Colour.MAGENTA);
        }

        if (c<35)
        {
            mod3.changeColour(Colour.RED);
        }
        if (c>= 35 && a<40)
        {
            mod3.changeColour(Colour.YELLOW);
        }   
        if (c>= 40 && a<70)
        {
            mod3.changeColour(Colour.GREEN);
        }
        if (c>= 70)
        {
            mod3.changeColour(Colour.MAGENTA);
        }

        if (d<35)
        {
            mod4.changeColour(Colour.RED);
        }
        if (d>= 35 && a<40)
        {
            mod4.changeColour(Colour.YELLOW);
        }   
        if (d>= 40 && a<70)
        {
            mod4.changeColour(Colour.GREEN);
        }
        if (d>= 70)
        {
            mod4.changeColour(Colour.MAGENTA);
        }

        if (e<35)
        {
            mod5.changeColour(Colour.RED);
        }
        if (e>= 35 && a<40)
        {
            mod5.changeColour(Colour.YELLOW);
        }   
        if (e>= 40 && a<70)
        {
            mod5.changeColour(Colour.GREEN);
        }
        if (e>= 70)
        {
            mod5.changeColour(Colour.MAGENTA);
        }

        if (f<35)
        {
            mod6.changeColour(Colour.RED);
        }
        if (f>= 35 && a<40)
        {
            mod6.changeColour(Colour.YELLOW);
        }   
        if (f>= 40 && a<70)
        {
            mod6.changeColour(Colour.GREEN);
        }
        if (f>= 70)
        {
            mod6.changeColour(Colour.MAGENTA);
        }
        //Colour changes depending on module mark
        //Could be improved
    }

    public static void printSummary(int[] moduleMarks)
    {
        for(int i =0; i<moduleMarks.length; i=i+1)
        {
            System.out.println("Module "+ (i+1) + " " + moduleMarks[i]);
        }
        //Prints module marks in a table
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm someone who usually hates it when people don't answer the question and just complain that it isn't a "valid" question. But this just strikes me as incredibly lazy. A quick google search on "java loops" and ten minutes of reading, and you would not have asked this question.

Comment: Also, a note about using "userXXX" as a username. It indicates to everyone here that you probably won't contribute anything to the community. Why not take the time to register an original username. Sorry, I'm done now. I'll stop being grouchy.

Comment: One of improvements would be creating method that takes `int` and `Bar` and depending on `a` changes color of `bar`. Now if you have all `bars` in array just iterate over them and use this method with current `bar` and value from `moduleMarks`.

Comment: Hey, even after seeing Vegard's solution I'm beginning to wrap my head around how I should have done it.  

I 100% want to help contribute to the community, its just at the moment I'm a newbie (and I wasn't aware I had to change my username!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    int horizontalMovement = 0;
    for (int moduleMark : moduleMarks) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.makeVisible();
        bar.moveVertical(200 - moduleMark);
        bar.changeSize(15, moduleMark);
        bar.moveHorizontal(horizontalMovement);
        horizontalMovement = horizontalMovement + 35;
        if (moduleMark < 35) {
            bar.changeColour(Colour.RED);
        } else if (moduleMark < 40) {
            bar.changeColour(Colour.YELLOW);
        } else if (moduleMark < 70) {
            bar.changeColour(Colour.GREEN);
        } else {
            bar.changeColour(Colour.MAGENTA);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is an awesome answer, could you explain a little more about what you've done with:

 `int moduleMark : moduleMarks`

Comment: It is Javas version of for each, it is well documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things you can do here:

```
    int a = moduleMarks[0];
    int b = moduleMarks[1];
    int c = moduleMarks[2];
    int d = moduleMarks[3];
    int e = moduleMarks[4];
    int f = moduleMarks[5];
```

Here you can make an int array:

```
int modules[] = new int[moduleMarks.length()];
```

Then you can go through with a for-loop and add:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   modules[i] = moduleMarks[i];
}
```

You can do similar changes to the rest of your code using this as inspiration.

Comment: Remember, if you are doing something similar many times over, it is often the case that you can use some kind of loop. If you don't know your loops I suggest reading some examples and trying them out, loops are after all some of the most important aspects of programming.

Comment: Why you want to copy one array to another if you can just use original one?

Answer (score 0):

Right now this code will only work if the elements in moduleMarks is only 6 elements long.  If there were 9 elements in that array only the first 6 would be drawn.  Sorta makes this code not terribly useful.  However, you can write code that will accept an array of any length and respond accordingly.

You've been given a hint how to start that process in the code you were given:

```
for(int i =0; i<moduleMarks.length; i=i+1)
{
    System.out.println("Module "+ (i+1) + " " + moduleMarks[i]);
}
```

That will iterate over every member of moduleMark regardless of length.  So you need to apply this idea to the rest of your program so that whatever draw is doing will work regardless of moduleMark's size.

You'll see there is a lot of code repeated for each element corresponding to a member in moduleMark.  Use loops to reduce that repeated code.  You'll have to model things with data (ie arrays) in order to rewrite that code using for loops.

I'm trying not to give the answer away because this is clearly homework and you should figure it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :D

It wasn't 'homework', just a project - and it was pointed out to me that it would be better if I made it more space efficient

Comment: I liked that answer +1 to to make it 0.

Comment: By homework I meant something that you were doing for a grade in a class to demonstrate some mastery of concepts.  A project could mean a project for a class which mostly around here is called homework.  If that's the case then I think it's important we don't tell you the answer and make you figure it out for yourself.

Answer (score -3):

Put your bars into an array (Bar[]).  Keep your moduleMarks in the array that they originally came in.  Then you can use a loop or set of nested loops:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < modArray.size; ++i) {
      modArray[i].makeVisible();
      modArray[i].moveVertical(200-moduleMarks[i]);
      modArray[i].changeSize(15, moduleMarks[i]);
      modArray[i].moveHorizontal(35*i);

      //etc.
 }
```

Comment: I hope you realize this is a person's homework, and by writing code for his person you aren't doing them any favors.